# Lambert W function

Tags: matlab

Consider the following problem: Given a value of c ≥ −1/e, find the value of x such that xe^x = c.

Use Newton’s method to solve equation  for values of c ≥ −1/e (Hint: solve the problem (c − xe^x = 0). Produce three tables showing convergence for your method for c = 0.5, c = 1, and c = 10 using the values produced by the function lambertw. Set the stopping criteria to  e= 10^−14. You may have to experiment around with making initial guesses.

```
a = 1;
f = @(x) c-x*e^x;
df = @(x) -1/x^2;
x0 = 2;
tol = 1e-15;
  for n = 1:MAX_ITER
  x(n+1) = x(n) - f(x(n))/df(x(n));
  if abs(x(n+1)-x(n)) < tol*abs(x(n+1))
    break;
  end
```

Honestly have no clue and I know my code makes no sense but I do not even know where to start. If I could get some help that would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your algorithm was already good, just some small adaptations are needed. 
In the first line I assume `a`should be `c`. The exponential is `exp(x)`, not `e^x`. Your derivative is wrong and`MAX_ITER` isn't defined. If you also change `x0` to `x(1)`, then it works.

I've been free to add a second loop for the different `c`, and save the iterations in a cell (in this case a 1x3 cell with each cell containing a vector):

```
cs = [.5,1,10];                                                             % different c values
f = @(x) c-x*exp(x);                                                        % function to solve
df = @(x) -(x+1)*exp(x);                                                    % derivative of function
u = cell(1,length(cs));                                                     % cell to save the different x while iterating 
tol = 1e-15;                                                                % tolerance
MAX_ITER = 10^10;                                                           % max number of iterations
for i=1:length(cs)                                                          % loop through different c
    c = cs(i);
    u{1}(1) = 2;                                                            % initial guess
    for n = 1:MAX_ITER
        u{i}(n+1) = u{i}(n) - f(u{i}(n))/df(u{i}(n));                   
        if abs(u{i}(n+1)-u{i}(n)) < tol*abs(u{i}(n+1))                      % check if ok
            break;
        end
    end
    assert(u{i}(end)*exp(u{i}(end)) == c, 'Correct solution not found')     % message if after MAX_ITER no solution is found
end
```